# jQuery onclick item not appending to div

Tags: jquery, html

In the code below it does not seem to be appending a new line of "item" to the three that I already have and I cannot seem to work out why:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SDRum/1/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div class ="formBlock menuDetails">
              <p><span class="bookingName">Menu<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="menu"/></span></p>
              <p><span class="bookingName">Item<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item" /></span></p>
              <p><span class="bookingName">Item<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item"/></span></p>
              <p><span class="bookingName">Item<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item"></span></p>

              <div class="appendMoreItems"></div>

              <div class="addMoreItemsButton">
              <a href="#" id="addItem">Add Item</a>
              </div>
        </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){

  $('<div/>', {
    'class' : 'menuDetails', html: getMenuHTMLDetails()
  }).appendTo('#addMoreItemsButton');
  $('#addItem').click(function () {
    $('<div/>', {
      'class' : 'extraMenuItem', html:getMenuHTMLDetails()
    }).hide().appendTo('#menuDetails').slideDown('slow');
  });
})

function getMenuHTMLDetails()
{
  var len    = $('.extraMenuItem').length;
  var $clone = $('.menuDetails').clone();

  $clone.find('[name=item]')[0].name="item"+len;
  return $clone.html();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be appending it to `.menuDetails` not `#menuDetails` (does not exist)

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'menuDetails',
        html: getMenuHTMLDetails()
    }).appendTo('#addMoreItemsButton');
    $('#addItem').click(function () {
        $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'extraMenuItem',
            html: getMenuHTMLDetails()
        }).hide().appendTo('.menuDetails').slideDown('slow');
    });
})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/SDRum/2/)**

Also, If you do little changes in your markup, You will get **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/SDRum/3/)** output

```
<div class="formBlock menuDetails">
    <p><span class="bookingName">Menu<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="menu"/></span>

    </p>
    <p><span class="bookingName">Item<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item" /></span>    
    </p>
    <p><span class="bookingName">Item<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item"/></span>    
    </p>
    <p><span class="bookingName">Item<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item" /></span>    
    </p>
    <div class="appendMoreItems"></div>
</div>
<div class="addMoreItemsButton"> <a href="#" id="addItem">Add Item</a></div> <!-- do not clone the this everytime -->
```

Comment: How can I make it so that I just get one "item" with input

Comment: @JessMcKenzie not sure what you are asking for

Comment: Instead of repeating the whole lot how can I make it just load "<p><span class="bookingName">Item<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item"></span></p>"

Comment: @JessMcKenzie which one worked for you? I will update my ans with same

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#addItem').click(function(){
    var toClone = $('p:last').clone();
    $('.appendMoreItems').append(toClone);
});
});
```